ImageMagick on wordpress 6.5.5 for Linux Alma 8 success but which no magick
I am trying to add a Page or an Entry and the message when trying to publish is the following:

The publication has failed. The response is not a valid JSON response.

I have also published my query in the servers section, since the installation of the imagemagick and the repository was satisfactory, however, it is not letting me publish Pages or Entries
Posted on Servers: https://serverfault.com/questions/1162647/imagemagick-for-linux-alma-8-success-but-which-no-magick
console:

network:


Could you please try to check browser dev tool console and network tab, it should show detailed error exactly what is causing the issue.

Thanks for the suggestion, add the console and network captures to the main query

I solved it adding a configuration on the htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

